# Does switching between \flushbottom and \raggedbottom affect page breaks?

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-breaking

Does switching between `\flushbottom` and `\raggedbottom` somehow affect page breaks (what words go on what pages) in addtion to how aesthetically pleasing a page looks?

Comment: you ask two unrelated questions `\flushbottom` and `\raggedbottom` do not change `\parskip`

Comment: Sorry. I will rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stretch glue (for raggedbottom) or lack of glue (for flushbottom) are added in the output routine to the box about to be shipped out after the page breaker has split off that box to form the current page.
So the settings only affect how the text is laid out on the page, not where page breaks happen.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely changing from `\flushbottom` to `\raggedbottom` affects the page setting, `\flushbottom` allows the variable space between text and heads and list and display math, etc. But `\raggedbottom` changes all spaces as fixed, i.e., it push the text from bottom to top...

Comment: I understand that it affects how things are laid out on the page, but I think OP was asking if it would affect between which two boxes the page would break.